# Continuous bijections over a compact space

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ be a compact space and $f: X \to Y$ a continuous bijection. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

---

I have managed to prove that $Y$ is compact too, and that $f$ is uniformly continuous. I don't see how that helps here.

Comment: The only sound result I have so far is that Y is also compact. Please only use basic notions when answering.

Comment: Please show us your attemps. We are not here for your homework.

Comment: @mundron-schmidt I had already left a comment and I edited it in. Sometimes you spend hours on a problem and find no leads.

Comment: Every open set maps to an open set.

Comment: @DougM That's what I have to show, indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true! For example let $X$ be a finite set, and let $\tau_d$ be the discrete topology (all subsets of $X$ open) on $X$ and $\tau_i$ the indiscrete topology (only open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$) on $X$. Then $\mathsf{id}_{(X, \tau_d)}$ is a continuous bijection, but clearly $\mathsf{id}_{(X, \tau_i)}$ is not going to be continuous.

Your theorem does however work if you make the additional assumption that $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: I guess I don't have the level to grasp all the words you're using, but to me a topology is the set of all opens over a vector space with a norm. I guess this makes my spaces Hausdorff?

I'm accepting your answer because you're technically right, but have also posted mine for further reference.

Comment: Your definition of a topology is more inline with that of a metric or normed space. Then indeed you spaces are Hausdorff. I would encourage you to check your definition of a topological space with that of the standard definition of a topological space, and those of a metric or a normed space.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a proof: let $F \subseteq X$ be a closed set, then it is a compact space. Thus, $f(F)$ is compact and therefore closed.

Therefore, the reciprocal of $f^{-1}$ maps closed sets to closed sets, and it is therefore continuous.

Comment: I guess this overlooks a lot of subtleties in topology, but I have not yet understood them.

Comment: A compact subspace of a compact space is closed if the space is Hausdorff, NOT in general.